# If statement hit when it shouldn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, countdowntimer

I am currently trying to write a simple countdowntimer. But if I take for example `10 hours` as an input the if statement for the minutes is still being triggered instead of the if statement for the hours. Because of this the code errors out like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clock.py", line 29, in <module>
    timer.timer(test_input)
  File "clock.py", line 6, in timer
    nt = int(nt)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 hours'
```

I think that this error message is not necessary to solve this problem because you can see very clearly that this error is caused because the wrong if statement is being triggered.

This is my code:

```
import time
class timer():
    def timer(test_input):
        if 'minutes' or 'minute' in test_input:    
            nt = test_input.replace('minutes','').replace('minute','')
            nt = int(nt)
            nt = int(nt*60)
            print(nt)
            while nt:
                mins, secs = divmod(nt, 60)
                timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
                print(timer, end="\r")
                time.sleep(1)
                nt -= 1 
        elif 'hours' or 'hour' in test_input:
            nt = test_input.replace('hours','').replace('hour','')
            nt = int(nt)
            nt = int(nt*3600)
            print(nt)
            while nt:
                mins, secs = divmod(nt, 60)
                timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
                print(timer, end="\r")
                time.sleep(1)
                nt -= 1 
           
        print('ALARM')
       
test_input = input('give me an input for your countdown: ')
timer.timer(test_input)
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code? If so I would be very glad if someone could explain to me what I've made wrong and how I can fix this problem.

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

PS: Feel free to question if you don't understand something of my code.

Comment: `if 'minutes' or 'minute' in test_input:`  will always evaluate to `True`. Non-empty strings have truthy values

Comment: `if "minute" in test_input` is enough. Same for the second if and "hour".

Comment: Right.  Python parses that statement as `if ('minutes') or ('minute' in test_input):`.  Since `minutes` is always "True", it won't even check the string match.

Comment: @Tim Roberts and the others I understand. Thank you very very much for your help guys:)